# cross apply sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi just learning sql server

this gives me an error :

```
 Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
```

Query:

```
SELECT p1.categoryid
    ,p1.productname
    ,p1.unitprice
FROM production.products AS p1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT min(p2.unitprice)
    FROM production.products AS p2
    WHERE p1.categoryid = p2.categoryid
    )
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? Do you want select sub query minimum unit price based on category id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give alias name to the sub query column as below:

```
min(p2.unitprice) unitprice
```

Answer (score 3):

You still need a table alias and to define the columns:

```
select p1.categoryid, p1.productname, p1.unitprice
from production.products p1 cross apply
     (select min(p2.unitprice) as minunitprice
      from production.products p2
      where p1.categoryid = p2.categoryid
     ) p2;
```

You are not selecting anything from the subquery.  I assume you intend:

```
select p1.categoryid, p1.productname, p1.unitprice, p2.minunitprice
from production.products p1 cross apply
     (select min(p2.unitprice) as minunitprice
      from production.products p2
      where p1.categoryid = p2.categoryid
     ) p2;
```

If so, you can write this as:

```
select p.*, min(p.unitprice) over (partition by p.categoryid)
from production.products p;
```

Comment: thanks but

When i add the alias i get this

No column name was specified for column 1 of 'a'.


select p1.categoryid, p1.productname, p1.unitprice
from production.products as p1
cross apply
(select min(p2.unitprice)
from production.products as p2
where p1.categoryid = p2.categoryid) as a

Comment: @Jody . . . Interesting.  I wasn't sure if the column name was needed because you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: @jody . . . As the OP you are free to choose to accept whichever answer you want.  I am curious, though, why you unaccepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

After cross apply block, you should add alias.

```
SELECT p1.categoryid
    ,p1.productname
    ,p1.unitprice
    ,X.min_unitPrice
FROM products AS p1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT min(unitprice) min_unitPrice
    FROM products  p2
    WHERE p1.categoryid = p2.categoryid
    ) X
```